# How to display GPS signal strength and accuracy? Android

Tags: android, gps, signals, status

I want to make a simple activity which opens and displays GPS signal strength and accuracy. I understand you use:

```
locationManager.getGpsStatus();
```

AND

```
location.getAccuracy();
```

This activity is going to be displayed within the 'Preference menu' (i'll have a preference that says "GPS Signal Status" - that can show the user a basic signal strength and accuracy.

However, I am finding it difficult to implement. I have already created a Google Maps Activity which shows user location. I just want it to display the status in this preference, giving the user an "advanced" function.

Cheers,

Zukky.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy field is populated from the location each time onLocationChanged() is triggered, it is not available 'on demand'. The accuracy can vary wildly between successive fixes. The usual method of conveying this information to the user is to superimpose a semi-transparent circular overlay with a radius equal to the accuracy on top of the displayed map.

'Signal strength' is not a field that can be obtained from a location. You can get fields corresponding to the SNR for each satellite and a measure of 'quality' if you implement a **NmeaListener** in your activity and write your own NMEA parser to extract the data. NMEA records are listed [here](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm).